# Get to second tr in data row table, Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to grab sports data.

```
allgames= driver.find_element_by_id("games")

box=allgames.find_element_by_link_text("Box Score")
```

This works, but it only grabs the box score form the first game (which is from `tr data-row="0"`)

I am trying to find a way where I can go to `tr data-row="1"` and then use `.find_element_by_link_text("Box Score")`

PICTURE OF HTML:

[image]

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath or css to get these elements. See Selenium's [examples](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) of these methods.

In your case:

```
trs = allgames.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr")
```

This gives you all the `tr` elements in the element stored in `allgames`.

Comment: and how to i get to tr data-row="1"? I am looking for .find_element_by_link_text("Box Score") in each tr data row... how to I call that

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you might go about this.

```
# find all tr tags within the game
tr_list = allgames.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
# select the Box Score
tr_list[1].find_element_by_link_text("Box Score")
```

An alternative way would be to use xpath as [@Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49101614/6233386) suggested but to specify the exact attribute you want.

```
# find the tr tag within the game with data-row=1
tr = allgames.find_element_by_xpath('//tr[@data-row="1"]')
# select the Box Score
tr.find_element_by_link_text("Box Score")
```